# Newest Java Runtime Environment (JRE) in 32 and 64 bit

Tags: java

I just want to download the newest JRE in 32 and in 64 bit!

At the download page of java.com I can only find an installer, but I just want to download the -maybe zipped- folder.

Can you help me where I can get this?

Thanks for your help!

Kind regards

Comment: why would you even want to download it as a zip?

Comment: The next question probaby will be, "I downloaded zip, unpacked it and JRE does not work as expected." What is the purpose to get Java Runtime Environment as a zip file ?

Comment: The purpose is that in my company many computers uses Java programs. And I want all computers to use the same Java installation.. I would copy the the jre folder to a network folder and would use this installation when the programs are launched.

Answer (score 2):

No, there are no official portable zipped distributions, but you can make one yourself, it's quite simple. Here's an instruction on how to do it for JDK 7 (for JDK 8 the procedure should not be different):

http://www.brucalipto.org/java/how-to-create-a-portable-jdk-1-dot-7-on-windows/

In a nutshell, you should unpack the .exe file as a 7-zip archive and rename all of the *.pack.jar files inside to corresponding *.jar files (just remove ".pack" from their names).